# how do i use TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() to solve UI update on background thread exception

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.5

Here is a small example of my problem, and I havent been able to solve it from the other questions about the same error.

UI Thread calls a function from a button click that has the following line:

```
await DataSet.AddFileAsync(String.Format("ms-appdata:///local/IMM_FACE_DB/{0}", file.Name));
```

AddFileAsync looks like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Model> Data {get;set;}
public Task AddFileAsync(string path)
{
     return Task.Factory.StartNew((state) =>
     {
         // Here some IO and computation is done, eventually some content is added 
         // to Data. Data is also bound to a GridView and this fails.

         //I assumed that TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
         // would solve this, but it does not.
     }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

As i have written in the code above, I assumed that the TaskScheduler could make sure it was run on the UI thread. Since the AddFileAsync is called from Databound Buttonclick Command.

Where have i misunderstood something? and what would be the correct wait to do this.

Comment: Can you give more detail on what you mean by `...and this fails`?

Comment: It was the exception that the ui was being updated from background thread. But as the answer below pointed out. I misunderstood something basics about async/wait coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for `StartNew` that I can see...

```
public async Task AddFileAsync(string path)
{
  // Do some IO
  var ioResult = await DoIoAsync(path);

  // Do some computation
  var computationResult = await Task.Run(() => DoComputation(ioResult));

  // Update Data
  Data.Add(computationResult);
}
```

Comment: looks like i missed out the part about not needing to return a Task

Comment: When you mark a method as `async`, a `Task` is created for you. It is also possible to return a `Task` from a non-`async` method, but there's no need to do that here.